# Rewriting Maxwell's equation in tensor form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, tensor-calculus

Suppose $F_{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}B_k $, how to prove the following:

1. $\partial_iB_i=0$ becomes $\partial_iF_{jk}+\partial_jF_{ki}+\partial_kF_{ij}=0$
2. $B_iB_i$ becomes $F_{ij}F_{ij}/2$

I can see that it is true by writing out all the combinations in 1,2,3, but how to prove it neatly and elegantly? Are there are tricks or identities that I can use?

Comment: In principle you could define electric field and magnetic field as 4-velocity of the observer contracted with $F$ and $*F$ (Hodge dual) respectively. However I never found it useful in anyway. I advise that you check that tensor form of Maxwell equations is constistent with vector form by hand, and later in tensor calculations just forget about E and B.

Comment: @Blazej Those definitions are useful in relativistic MHD, where we want covariant objects but at the same time don't need all of $F$ (since perfect conductivity combined with knowledge about the fluid velocity makes half the information in $F$ redundant).

Comment: That's quite interesting, I must admit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\partial_iB_i = 0$ 
$$
\partial_iB_i = \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_iF_{jk} = 0
$$
The Levi-Civita symbol permutes so that $\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{jki}$ $= \epsilon_{kij}$ we can write
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_iF_{jk} + \epsilon_{jki}\partial_jF_{ki} + \epsilon_{kij}\partial_kF_{ij} = 0,
$$
since each of these vanish, and we collect the permuted Levi-Civita symbols
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\left(\partial_iF_{jk} + \partial_jF_{ki} + \partial_kF_{ij}\right) = 0.
$$
The result is in the parentheses.

As for the second of these we write
$$
B_iB_i = \epsilon_{ijk}F_{jk}\epsilon_{imn}F_{mn}
$$
and we use the identity $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn} = \delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} -\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$ to see that
$$
B_iB_i = F_{jk}F_{jk} - F_{jk}F_{kj}  = 2F_{jk}F_{jk},
$$
where the last equal sign used the antisymmetry of the EM field tensor $F_{jk}$. This then gives $\frac{1}{2}|B|^2 = \frac{1}{4}|F|^2$.

Comment: How do you get the first line? Does $F_{jk}=\epsilon_{jki}B_{i}$ always imply $B_{i}=\epsilon_{jki}F_{jk}$?

Comment: Essentially that is so. The summation over the Levi-Civita symbol generates factors of $2$ or  $\frac{1}{2}$, which I have been a bit cavalier about here. I leave it to you to get the fiddle factors worked out.